# Create a new column in a CSV file based on the values of 2 other columns

Tags: csv, awk

I have a CSV with 23 columns containing data from a network scan. I need to create a new column based on the data from the last 2 columns (22 and 23). My desired output is as follows:

New column heading = Labelled

```
if column 22 = Malicious and column 23= C&C-FileDownload then new column 24= 1
```

Can someone help me achieve this using Ubuntu? I've been looking into this and I can see awk is the tool to use but I'm very new to this.

So far I've tried this:

```
awk 'NR==1{$24="merge";print;next} \ $22 == "Malicious" || $23 == "C&C-FileDownload" {$24=1}1' Malware-44-1.csv > test1.csv
```

However, this doesn't add the new columns with "1"; it does add "Merged" as a column but doesn't comma delimit it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi,I've tried this:awk 'NR==1{$24="merge";print;next} \
$22 == "Malicious" || $23 == "C&C-FileDownload" {$24=1}1' Malware-44-1.csv > test1.csv , it prints "Merge as a header, but not comma deliminated, and it doesn't add 1 to a new column. Although there are 23 csv columns I think its seeing every character as a column.

Comment: Please add all attempts to your question by editing it

Comment: I've added the attempt to the question but it has been closed. Can this be re-opend or do I need to re-post?

Comment: With the latest edits, this question should be reopened

Comment: Please share sample input file that produces bad results. Also, consider simplifying the problem - you should try to solve this for 4 column files

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell awk that

1. the input is a CSV (using `-F`) (it's assuming whitespace separators, so the numbering isn't what you're expecting, you're getting lucky with `$24`),
2. the output field separator `OFS` has to be set to a comma, too:

`awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","} your_code_here '`